# How to get URL magento admin page from within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, magento, modal-dialog

I am following this tutorial as a reference:
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-popup-dialog/

My situation is this, I have a .js file that has a function to open a popup dialog, however I needed this dialog was opened starting from product registration, so I put the following code in my installation module:

```
'note'     => '<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showDialogCategory();">AAAAAAA</a>'
```

who gave me this result
[image]

he comes to open the dialog usually opens blank however, and have to pass a URL as a parameter, but I knew how.

I tried unsuccessfully as follows:

```
'note'     => '<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showDialogCategory('''."<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/mymodule_categorysel') ?>".''');">AAAAAAA</a>'
```

Alone page usually works

Thank you

Comment: It's not available in the JS by default, but you can create a global variable for it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60111/get-base-url-in-js-magento

Comment: I could tell me how I fit it in my situation? because I do not have to create this variable the way I'm using

Comment: @ Jose: I hope you will be aware that magento is using the Prototype js So it may be possible that you might be getting the conflicts at JS level due to which your code may not work

Comment: My code works, however I just need to pass the URL as a parameter to the function in Javascript, this URL is admin then I have to use
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/mymodule_categorysel')

what I do not know how to do, how to get that url in the way I'm doing?